# How can i avoid black bar in iframe videos?

Tags: iframe, video

Here is the code for iframe video:

```
<div>
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/135943631?autoplay=0&color=c9ff23&
title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0" 
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Now it shows like [**this**](http://s28.postimg.org/wjhaeqqsd/untitled.jpg).

May i know how to avoid this black bar below and above the video.

I tried using following code:

```
  .videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
  .videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 0;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/135943631?autoplay=0&
color=c9ff23&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="800px" height="450px" 
frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

Note: I should not change height. Because i need big size video.

Can Any one suggest me, how can i achieve this?

Comment: can anyone help me please?..

Comment: so height occupied by black bars should not be changed ? if so.. making that color to white would suffice ?

Comment: nope.. not color.. I need to expand the video.. thanks

Comment: you mean to say video height will occupy the height previously occupied by black bars ? if so what about aspect ratio!!

Answer (score 0):

The black bars are appearing because your video is in aspect ratio of 16:9 and you are trying to fit with inside iframe of 1000px/1000px. 
So your height is scaled according to aspect ratio, i.e., video height is 1000 * 9/16 = ~584px and remaining 420px are empty. Since vimeo has the video background as black color, this empty space is appearing as black bars.

To fix your problem, its better to have iframe with width/height in 16:9 ratio. (example: width: 800px; height: 450px)

Comment: <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/135943631?autoplay=0&color=c9ff23&
title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="800" height="450" frameborder="0"  .......    only changed width and height

Comment: so you want to have width 100% without any blackbars on top and bottom right ?  then please try viewport specific height/width.

Comment: <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/135943631?autoplay=0&color=c9ff23&
title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="display: block; height: 100vh;    width: 100vw;" frameborder="0"

Comment: Nope.. can you help me?

Comment: Let me know your exact requirement w.r.t width and height.

Comment: After i tried javascripts, it has removed black bars.. and also i got full width.. but now, i have to decrease the height of video.. when i reduce the height, it will cut the video image.. so here i m stuck... thanks